# navigation menu not show up on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to find out why my navigation window not showing up when I visit my page using mobile devices and iPad?

Any idea please that can help?

http://egycotravel.com/trips.html

Thanks

sorry : this link have the navigation bar that i am talking about , it have orange background and white text links . when i am opening this URL on my mobile , the navigation links not showing up ... i wonder why ?

Comment: What is this link? Is it the page you are talking about or what? Please clarify.

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you be more specific about the problem you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find and modify this CSS code in your style.css file:

```
ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}
ul.topnav li:hover {
    background:url(images/bg_hover.png) repeat;
}

ul.topnav li a{
    padding: 10px 2px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    color: #3333CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks teddybeaed , its working :)